# Only these six belong but which, where and why?

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

The two ellipses represent as-yet-unknown categories and of all the countries only the six shown belong to at least one of the categories. One is placed for you and for the remainder which belong where and why?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These countries can be classified like this:

> [image: (CH AU (DE) NZ EE IE)]
>
>  The names of the countries' capitals contain **BER** or **LIN**. **Ber**n and Can**ber**ra have only **BER**; Wel**lin**gton, Tal**lin**n and Dub**lin** have only **LIN** and **Berlin** has both.

Comment: Always surprised at how quickly some people solve these!

Answer (score 0):

It could also be...

> I thought it was European countries and island countries. Ireland being both an island and in Europe.

Comment: "... of all the countries only the six shown belong to at least one of the categories" ‒ surley there are more European countries and more island countries in the world than those six.